# Querying display power status on Linux (Xorg) on command line

Tags: x11, power-management

Is there a way to query the power status of an Xorg/X11 display from command line? I want to know if my laptop LCD is powered on after the screen saver--apparently the backlight is still on. This is despite my gnome-screensaver-preferences setting that after 5 minutes of idling, the display is supposed to go to sleep. I am using Debian 6 and whatever x server comes with it.

I see that `upower` utility has some nifty switches, but they are not documented.

Answer (score 5):

To test whether your monitor is on or off you can use

```
$ xset q | grep Monitor
Monitor is On
```

In order to determine the brightness of your LCD backlight you can run

```
$ xbacklight
70.000000
```

Comment: The xset that comes with Debian 6 (or more recent Fedora 18 for that matter) does not show monitor status like yours. Which distro is it?

The xbacklight utility is good to know (despite not doing/showing what I wanted). Thank you though.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (is based on Debian) with the proprietary nvidia driver. Maybe it's a driver capability.